# In highcharts,tool-tip does not move when chart has high data unlike when it has low data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In `highcharts`, when I add data using `addpoint()` allowing `'shift'` to `'true'`, the tool-tip does not move when it has large data just like how it moves when it has low data. the amount of data can be recognised by changing range of rangeSelector. Is there anything I can modify or should I include some extra code. I have reproduced the issue in below link.

https://jsfiddle.net/1y3gmkt5/

```js
// Create the chart
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function () {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series1 = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function () {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                    series1.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }, 2000);
                var series2 = this.series[1];
                setInterval(function () {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = Math.round(Math.random() * 50);
                    series2.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
    },

    time: {
        useUTC: false
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [{
            count: 1,
            type: 'minute',
            text: '1M'
        }, {
            count: 5,
            type: 'minute',
            text: '5M'
        }, {
            type: 'all',
            text: 'All'
        }],
        inputEnabled: false,
        selected: 0
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
    },

    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
legend: {
                enabled: true
            },
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true,
                        animation: {duration: 100},
                        enableMouseTracking: true,
                        stickyTracking: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

tooltip:{
        shared: true,
                split: false,
         stickyTracking: true,
                enableMouseTracking: true,
                enabled: true,
                followPointer: true,
                followTouchMove: true,
          formatter: function(){
                var tooltip = "";
                var phaseNameList = "";
                
                //tooltip += "<b>I-unit "+ "<br/>"+ "x: "+this.x +"</b>";
                tooltip += "<b>I-unit "+ "<br/>"+ "x: "+ new Date(this.x)+
                "</b>";
                tooltip +=  "<br/>"+ "y: "+this.y +"</b>";
                tooltip +=  "<br/>"+ this + "</b>";
                return tooltip;
               }
},

    series: [{
        name: 'Random data1',
        data: (function () {
            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                data.push([
                    time + i * 1000,
                    Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                ]);
            }
            return data;
        }())
    },
    {
    name: 'Random data2',
        data: (function () {
            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                data.push([
                    time + i * 1000,
                    Math.round(Math.random() * 50)
                ]);
            }
            return data;
        }())
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

**expected result:** when mouse pointer is hovered over any marker and left as it is, then tool-tip should move behind as and when new data arrives. Currently works fine when range selector has low data but not when there is large data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by `dataGrouping` property that modifies the data. You can disable it by:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataGrouping: {
            enabled: false
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

---

**Code snippet:**

```js
// Create the chart
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function() {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series1 = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function() {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                    series1.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }, 2000);
                var series2 = this.series[1];
                setInterval(function() {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = Math.round(Math.random() * 50);
                    series2.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
    },

    time: {
        useUTC: false
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [{
            count: 1,
            type: 'minute',
            text: '1M'
        }, {
            count: 5,
            type: 'minute',
            text: '5M'
        }, {
            type: 'all',
            text: 'All'
        }],
        inputEnabled: false,
        selected: 0
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
    },

    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataGrouping: {
                enabled: false
            },
            marker: {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true,
                        animation: {
                            duration: 100
                        },
                        enableMouseTracking: true,
                        stickyTracking: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        split: false,
        stickyTracking: true,
        enableMouseTracking: true,
        enabled: true,
        followPointer: true,
        followTouchMove: true,
        formatter: function() {
            var tooltip = "";
            var phaseNameList = "";

            //tooltip += "<b>I-unit "+ "<br/>"+ "x: "+this.x +"</b>";
            tooltip += "<b>I-unit " + "<br/>" + "x: " + new Date(this.x) +
                "</b>";
            tooltip += "<br/>" + "y: " + this.y + "</b>";
            tooltip += "<br/>" + this + "</b>";
            return tooltip;
        }
    },

    series: [{
            name: 'Random data1',
            data: (function() {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;

                for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data.push([
                        time + i * 1000,
                        Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                    ]);
                }
                return data;
            }())
        },
        {
            name: 'Random data2',
            data: (function() {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;

                for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data.push([
                        time + i * 1000,
                        Math.round(Math.random() * 50)
                    ]);
                }
                return data;
            }())
        }
    ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k52rnhya/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.enabled

Comment: This is great. could you pls add the snippet here ? It would look even better

Comment: Hi @Towkir, Yes, sure.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek,there was an another issue which I tried to fix but I could not find the solution could you please help in fixing it? the issue is "milliseconds data is not plotting when chart has high data,but it is displayed when exported. i.e data is present for every second while plotting but not for every millisecond. Whereas when exported all data is present." Can you please check once.

Comment: it is happening with the high frequency data specifically history data and when zoomed in.

Comment: @ppotaczek please check the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56662558/the-milliseconds-data-is-not-present-in-the-history-data-of-highcharts

Comment: Hi @mukhtar alam, Ok, we will continue the thread in the new topic.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, could you please check this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052823/aligning-the-xaxis-of-highcharts